# Batch: How to append the name of a variable instead of the value of that variable

Tags: string, variables, batch-file, append

I am trying to append strings to a text file. So far, my code looks like this:

```
echo -%appointment% >>C:\Users\Evan\Desktop\Programming\Events.txt
echo set /a h=(%hours%*3600)+(%minutes%*60) >>C:\Users\Evan\Desktop\Programming\Events.txt
echo set /a i=%day%-%dbf% >>C:\Users\Evan\Desktop\Programming\Events.txt
echo if %g% leq %h% if %b% equ %day% echo %appointment% %time% Today >>C:\Users\Evan\Desktop\Programming\Events.txt
echo if %b% lss %day% if %b% geq %i% echo %appointment% %time% %date% >>C:\Users\Evan\Desktop\Programming\Events.txt
```

The problem is, the variables `%b%` and `%g%` are dependent on the specific occurance. `%b%` and `%g%` change with date, so while their values will be accurate when I append them into the text file, their values will NOT be accurate when I actually want to convert the text file into a batch file and use it. How do I literally append the variable `%b%` as text and not its current value so that it can change every time I run the text file as a batch? If I try to append `"%b%"` in code with those quotations, in the occuring file, it is simply output as "".

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double the `%` for the `%` you wish to output literally.

`%` escapes `%` (ie causes it to be interpreted as an ordinary, not a special character.)

`^` escapes most awkward characters like `|` - but not `%`

Comment: This works great. I just set b="b" and in the append line I put ...%%b%%. Funnily enough, I had just come up with this method myself and finished testing it before I came to this page to post my solution. :D Thanks so much!